# Why is map() only displaying the last object in the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently learning React and I am trying to render my JSON data to the page. I used the map(), however it is only rendering the last object from the array onto the page.

```
class ContentCard extends Component {
  state = {
    products: ProductInfo
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.products);
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.products.map(items => (
          <div className="container page-wrapper">
            <div className="page-inner">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="el-wrapper">
                  <div className="box-up">
                    <img className="img" src={items.img} alt="" />
                    <div className="img-info">
                      <div className="info-inner">
                        <span className="p-name">{items.name}</span>
                        <span className="p-company">{items.company}</span>
                        <span className="price">
                          {items.price.toLocaleString("en-US", {
                            style: "currency",
                            currency: "USD"
                          })}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Json Data. The image links would have been too long so i just added a sample image to make it easier to read.

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 1000,
    company: "YEEZY",
    categoryName: "Men",
    category: "tShirt",
    name: "I feel like Pablo",
    img: "http://code.slicecrowd.com/labs/4/images/t-shirt.png",
    price: 120.0
  },
  {
    id: 1000,
    company: "H&M",
    categoryName: "Men",
    category: "tShirt",
    name: "butterfly",
    img: "http://code.slicecrowd.com/labs/4/images/t-shirt.png",
    price: 120.0
  },

  {
    id: 1000,
    company: "North Face",
    categoryName: "Men",
    category: "Jacket",
    name: "WindBreaker",
    img: "http://code.slicecrowd.com/labs/4/images/t-shirt.png",
    price: 120.0
  }
];

export default products;
```

Comment: Looks like some of your code is cutoff such as the ")" and "}". Could you please include the entire return statement. Also, throw in your CSS as well. If your map function ends up being fine, the issue might be your styling i.e. boxes sitting on top of each other.

Comment: Please also share `this.state.products` or the original JSON literal.

Comment: What does your `console.log(this.state.products)` print?

Comment: console.log(this.state.products) prints the entire array

Comment: @Hyetigran May be on to something, have you inspected the DOM to see what is being rendered to confirm anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a key when you render multiple items in an array.

```
array.map(item => (
  <div key={item.unique_property}>
    [...]
  </div>
))
```

Also, are you definitely on React 16.2 + ? I.e. do you have the necessary Fragment syntax support?

Comment: i am using React v16.13.1

Answer (score 0):

This example could help you:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyPost = () => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('url')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(jsonData => setPost([...jsonData]));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {post.length > 0 ? (
        <ol>
          {post.map(p => (
            <li key={p.replace(/' '/g, '')}>{p}</li>
          ))}
        </ol>
      ) : (
        <h1>No post Available</h1>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default MyPost;
```